# Tkinter Class method

Tags: python, class, tkinter

Okay, i've been trying to create a small text editor in Tkinter. I've stubble across a problem and I can't seem to find the answer. If anyone could just help me, I'd be very happy.

First of all, here is my code :

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as tkfile


class PyTedi(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        # Instantiate Menu
        main_menu = tk.Menu(self)
        menu_bar = PyTediMenu(main_menu)
        main_menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=menu_bar)
        self.config(menu=main_menu)

        # Instantiate Text Area
        text_area = PyTediTextArea(self)
        text_area.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

        # Instantiate Tool Bar
        tool_bar = PyTediToolBar(self)
        tool_bar.pack(side=tk.TOP)


class PyTediMenu(tk.Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Menu.__init__(self, parent)

        self.add_command(label='New', command=None)
        self.add_command(label='Open', command=None)
        self.add_command(label='Save', command=tkfile.asksaveasfile)
        self.add_separator()
        self.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.quit)        


class PyTediToolBar(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, height=30)


class PyTediTextArea(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, parent)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = PyTedi()
    app.mainloop()
```

Basically, I've found out, (From another stack question) That it is a good idea to create class based components... My problem is, let's say I want to create a command -> Save File. So I create a method inside my Menu and link to the save function. BUT, how do I grab the text area content and write it to a file ? They are not even part of the same class. Is it a bad design implementation or it's just me ?
Thanks !

Comment: You could pass a reference to your main class or the text field to be saved to the menu.

Comment: How would you do that ? Sorry I'm kind of a beginner... And would it be better to define methods inside a application to initiate a program ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while it is a good idea to use class based programming, i would like to point out that unless you are modifying the widget in some way, subclassing it is completely unnecessary, when you create the class `PyTediTextArea` you aren't actually modifying the original text class in any way, so it would be simpler for you to simply change

```
text_area = PyTediTextArea(self)
```

to

```
self.text_area = tk.Text(self)
```

that way you save yourself subclassing at the bottom and from anywhere in your main class you can simply call

```
self.text_area.get(0, "end")
```

to get all of the text in the widget

James

Comment: That's what I will be doing ! Thanks !